# IE7/IE8 takes some time to return the correct scroll position

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scroll, restore, scrolltop

For displaying a dialog, I need to know the current scroll position of the window. This is done within a `$(document).ready` block of jQuery.

Internet Explorer, however, breaks things when having to remember the scroll position.

You can try this by opening the following HTML code in IE, scroll down a bit and hit reload (sorry I didn't create a fiddle – because of the scrolling it would not work there).

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"     
type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert(document.body.scrollTop);
    alert(document.body.scrollTop);
  });
</script>

<div style="height:4000px;">
</div>
```

The first `alert` shows `0`, the second one shows the correct number. It also works without the first alert if I use `setTimeout` and wait for (in my case) 20msecs - which of couse might take another amount of time in other circumstances and therefore is no solution.

I think the problem is that IE first scrolls top, does some things, and then, after a while, restores the previous scrolling position (probably it has to render things first in order to make sure that this scroll position still exists at all).

Is there any propper way of getting the browser scroll right at once?

Comment: can you somehow rule out that $().ready() is causing the delays?

Comment: No, I don't think it's causing the delays but rather called / hooked in too early: IE does not seem fully ready at the time the ``ready()`` callbacks are called.

Comment: Is your web application very slow by performance?

Comment: I don't think that that's the problem – try the sample above (should not be of slow performance, right?).

Answer (score 0):

There are several properties to get page scroll, and it's different in every browser.
Here is a function I wrote in order to receive the correct scroll:

```
function getScroll(type)
{
    type = type || 'top';

    var result = 0;
    var scroll = 0;
    if (type === 'top')
    {
        if (ISQ.Http.browser.app !== 'ie' || ISQ.Http.browser.isIE9)
            scroll = window.pageYOffset;
        if (ISQ.Http.browser.app !== 'ie')
            scroll = returnMaxScroll(scroll, window.scrollY);
        scroll = returnMaxScroll(scroll, document.body.scrollTop);
        scroll = returnMaxScroll(scroll, document.documentElement.scrollTop);
        scroll = returnMaxScroll(scroll, document.body.parentNode.scrollTop);
    }
    else if (type === 'left')
    {
        if (ISQ.Http.browser.app !== 'ie' || ISQ.Http.browser.isIE9)
            scroll = window.pageXOffset;
        if (ISQ.Http.browser.app !== 'ie')
            scroll = returnMaxScroll(scroll, window.scrollX);
        scroll = returnMaxScroll(scroll, document.body.scrollLeft);
        scroll = returnMaxScroll(scroll, document.documentElement.scrollLeft);
        scroll = returnMaxScroll(scroll, document.body.parentNode.scrollLeft);
    }
    else if (type === 'height')
    {
        switch (ISQ.Http.browser.app)
        {
            case "chrome":
            case "ff":
            case "opera":
            case "safari":
                // iframe
                if (window.top === window)
                    scroll = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
                // top window
                else
                    scroll = document.body.scrollHeight;
                break;
            default:
                scroll = returnMaxScroll(scroll, document.body.scrollHeight);
                scroll = returnMaxScroll(scroll, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
                scroll = returnMaxScroll(scroll, document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight);
                break;

        }
    }
    else if (type === 'width')
    {
        scroll = returnMaxScroll(scroll, document.body.scrollWidth);
        scroll = returnMaxScroll(scroll, document.documentElement.scrollWidth);
        scroll = returnMaxScroll(scroll, document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth);
    }

    return scroll;
}
function returnMaxScroll(value1, value2)
{
    if (value1 > value2) return value1;
    return value2;
}
```

```
FYI: you may need to implement these booleans:
- ISQ.Http.browser.app !== 'ie'
- ISQ.Http.browser.isIE9
```

I hope it'll help you :)

Comment: Thank's a lot! I'll try it asap!

Comment: what is the test for ie8?